# What is the best practice for using clojure.repl functions during interacitve development?

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, cider

I often find myself typing `(ns user)` and pressing <kbd>C+c</kbd> <kbd>M+n</kbd> repeatedly when I work on clojure source code. The problem is that I often use functions like `source` and `doc` and they are in `clojure.repl` and I don't want to `:require` them to my namespaces. What are experienced clojurians doing in this case?

**Clarification:** I know how clojure's namespacing works. What I want to achieve is to be able to call `(source myfunc)`,`(doc myfunc)` etc. without the need to use fully qualified names in the REPL **and** without the need to require the functions from `clojure.repl` in each of my namespaces.

Comment: In [my workflow](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126376/82369), I like to keep a separate source file to hold my `user` namespace and all its dependencies. For instance, when I'm not using [Component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component), the contents of my `dev/user.clj` file usually look something like this: `(ns user (:require [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]] [clojure.repl :refer [doc source]]))`

Comment: You mentioned `C-c M-n`. If you're using CIDER in Emacs, `M-.` does the equivalent of `source`. And `C-d d d` `doc`. You don't need to type `myfunc` is point is already on that text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for clearing up what you are asking for.

Leiningen has a feature called **:injections** which you can [combine with vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa) to get this effect If you put something like this in your leiningen profile:

~/lein/profiles.clj:

```
{:user {:plugins []
        :dependencies [[im.chit/vinyasa "0.1.8"]]
        :injections [(require 'vinyasa.inject)
                      (vinyasa.inject/inject
                       'clojure.core '>
                       '[[clojure.repl doc source]
                         [clojure.pprint pprint pp]])]}}
```

Because this is in your profiles.clj it only affects you. Other people who work on the project won't be affected.

---

Because injecting into clojure.core strikes me as a little iffy, I follow the vinyasa author's advice and inject into a namespace called . which is crated by my profile for every project I work on. This namespace always exists which makes these function work even in newly created namespaces that don't yet refer clojure.core.

My ~/.lein/profiles.clj:

```
{:user
  {:plugins []
   :dependencies [[spyscope "0.1.4"]
                  [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.4"]
                  [io.aviso/pretty "0.1.8"]
                  [im.chit/vinyasa "0.4.7"]]
   :injections
   [(require 'spyscope.core)
    (require '[vinyasa.inject :as inject])
    (require 'io.aviso.repl)
    (inject/in ;; the default injected namespace is `.`

               ;; note that `:refer, :all and :exclude can be used
               [vinyasa.inject :refer [inject [in inject-in]]]
               [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
               [clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]]
               [clojure.repl :refer [doc source]]
               [vinyasa.maven pull]
               [vinyasa.reflection .> .? .* .% .%> .& .>ns .>var])]}}
```

which works like this:

```
hello.core> (./doc first)
-------------------------
clojure.core/first
([coll])
  Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its
    argument. If coll is nil, returns nil.
nil
hello.core> (in-ns 'new-namespace)
#namespace[new-namespace]
new-namespace> (./doc first)
nil
new-namespace> (clojure.core/refer-clojure)
nil
new-namespace> (./doc first)
-------------------------
clojure.core/first
([coll])
  Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its
    argument. If coll is nil, returns nil.
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you may use [vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa) library, in particular its [`inject`](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa#inject) functionality. Basically you need to add needed functions from `clojure.repl` namespace to `clojure.core` namespace. After you won't need to require them explicitly. See the following:

```
user> (require '[vinyasa.inject :refer [inject]])
nil

;; injecting `source` and `doc` symbols to clojure.core
user> (inject '[clojure.core [clojure.repl source doc]]) 
[]

;; switching to some other namespace
user> (require 'my-project.core)
nil
user> (in-ns 'my-project.core)
#namespace[my-project.core]

;; now those functions are accessible w/o qualifier
my-project.core> (doc vector) 
-------------------------
clojure.core/vector
([] [a] [a b] [a b c] [a b c d] [a b c d e] [a b c d e f] [a b c d e f & args])
  Creates a new vector containing the args.
nil
```